# Magento 1.9 Rest API - Fetch Product Data with Custom Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes, rest-api

I am using module (in Magento 1.9.3.10) that extends the default `Mage/Product model` by adding a new attribute named `Status` with a corresponding file named `Status.php` residing in `Package\ModuleName\Model\Catalog\Product\Attribute`.
The `Status` attribute also extends `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`.

If I try to access the REST API for products on either my development and production servers (with the required OAuth parameters), i.e `http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products` causes a 500 internal error whiles every other rest endpoint do not fail.

How can I include the custom attribute in the REST API without causing 500 internal errors?

NB: I am using an OAuth consumer which has been verified and I am able to fetch products IFF the custom module is uninstalled

Comment: you need to pass admin token

Comment: Please read the NB I have appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the cause of the problem. An observer was set on `catalog_product_collection_load_before`.
It called a function that tries to access the the details of the user through `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()`. Unfortunately, this returns `null` when it is a REST call.